# for loop with if statement not showing list of lists result

Tags: python-3.x, list

below is my code and there are two version. First, *for* loop without *if* statement and second, *for* loop with *if* statement. From what I have found that, if I remove *if* statement on first version, the result will show all employees information. I'm still learning python and thanks in advance

```
def addNew():
    global employees
    newEmp = []
    checkList = []
    newEmp.append(input("Enter id: "))
    newEmp.append(input("Enter name: "))
    newEmp.append(input("Enter department: "))
    newEmp.append(input("Enter position: "))
    checkList.append(newEmp)

    for new in checkList:
        print(new)
        for exist in employees:
            print(exist)

result
['1001', 'das', 'das', 'das']  # from print(new)
['1000', 'tim', 'hr', 'admin'] # from print(exist)
['1003', 'jim', 'hr', 'clerk'] # from print(exist)
['1007', 'ida', 'hr', 'audit'] # from print(exist)
['1005', 'mia', 'itss', 'security'] # from print(exist)
```

However, on this second version code below, if I put the *if* statement in *for* loop the result will only show one employee information.

```
def addNew():
    global employees
    newEmp = []
    checkList = []
    newEmp.append(input("Enter id: "))
    newEmp.append(input("Enter name: "))
    newEmp.append(input("Enter department: "))
    newEmp.append(input("Enter position: "))
    checkList.append(newEmp)

    for new in checkList:
        print(new)
        for exist in employees:
            print(exist)
            if new[0] == exist[0]:
                print("entered id",new[0],"is already exist")
                break
            elif new[0] != exist[0]:
                employees.extend(checkList)
                break

result
['1001', 'das', 'das', 'das']  # from print(new)
['1000', 'tim', 'hr', 'admin'] # from print(exist)
```

Comment: The for loop ends because of the break statements. Remove them if you want to go through the whole list.

Comment: why why why. I have spend almost 2 hour how to solve this. thank you master @Heike

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because it either went inside the `if` statement or the `elif` statement and since both of them have a `break` statement, the inner loop is terminated immediately even though not all the `employees` have been gone through yet.

Comment: shame on me. why can't I saw this ```break``` cause my program not function as I expected. thank you for your help. :)